# Can the Date in a firestore query (onsnapshot) be kept current

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my web app I fire off a query to gather all recent messages for a user and then use an onsnapshot to show these messages in a feed. In my app some messages get posted to the future so I only want messages from now or earlier in the feed.

```
  var query = firebase.firestore()
                  .collection('messages')
                  .where('owner','==',userID)
                  .where('timestamp','<',new Date())
                  .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
                  .limit(25);
```

The user can then create new messages and I want those added to the feed displayed in the app. After adding a new message do I have to cancel the onSnapshot listener and execute a new query with an updated current Date? Or is there a way for this query to update the time lookup so that the onSnapshot is always getting newly posted messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change any of the query parameters, you need to build a new Query object with the new values and add a snapshot listener to it..

Comment: I decided to add an hour to the date so that any new message posts will appear dynamically in the feed vs rebuilding the query for every new post. I will probably put a check in later for whether the user has been active for longer than an hour and rebuild the query at that point. Managing time between client and server for a social app is just one of those things that is never easy. It would be wonderful if firebase updated queries based on changes in time!

Comment: So, if I have a snapshot listener on a query, and then the query parameters change, do I need to create a new query object? For example, if one of the parameters which is changing is stored in this.state (React-Native) and when updating it, wont it be updated in the query as well?